# How to set different filesystem for python os.path module?

Tags: python, ssh, operating-system

I'm developing a script that auto-deploys my Django project from my Windows machine to my local Raspberry server.

Amongst the steps, there's a python script that has to be copyied to the server, and executed there. I execute it through an SSH call from `paramiko` module:

```
client.exec_command('python ' + '/home/myname/projects/example_app/script.py')
```

This is one of the lines the executed script:

```
import os
import subprocess

sp.run("python " + os.path.join("/home/myname/projects", "example_app", "manage.py collectstatic"))
```

However, I get the following erro:

```
python: can't open file 'E:\\home\\myname\\projects\\example_app\\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Weirdly enough, seems like the os.path module is joining paths considering my Windows filesystem, even though the script is called from within the Linux server. Ok, I don't know about the SSH implementation, and I can accept that. My question is: **is there a way to manually set the OS for os.path module**?

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path, PurePosixPath, PureWindowsPath
def test():
    file = PurePosixPath('/home/myname/projects') / "example_app" / "manage.py"
    sp.run(f'python {file} collectstatic')
```

Note that `collectstatic` isn't part of the filename but is an argument passed to Python.  So it shouldn't be part of the pathname.

The module `pathlib` provides `Path`, `PurePosixPath`, and `PureWindowsPath`.  The first provides what's on the current platform.  The latter two have more limited functionality, but can be used to build appropriate filenames.